# central subscriber replication in Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

We have regional office and some data in this office.We want to transfer data from each regional office everyday to central office .For this reason I need central subscriber topology.I implement central subscriber transactional replication but I have a problem ,with transactional replication, if a new regional office want to join these replication,its database must  be empty but when a new software is install on new regional office it fill new database with some rows and then when I setup transactional replication , it dosen't transfer these data to central server, so I think that a merge replication is required .But i searched and didn't find any useful help for implementing "**central subscriber merge replication**"
.How can I implement "**central subscriber merge replication**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it with without client Initialization.